# Typescript Error in AWS Serets Manger Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to create write integration tests to test a login component using the AWS Client to retrieve secrets from Secrets Manager via the `@aws-sdk/types` library. The Credentials Interface from the `aws-sdk/types` library requires fields to be of type string, but I'm populating them with environment variables which aren't populated until my integration tests are run.

```
    export interface Credentials extends AwsCredentialIdentity {
    /**
     * AWS access key ID
     */
    readonly accessKeyId: string;
    /**
     * AWS secret access key
     */
    readonly secretAccessKey: string;
    /**
     * A security or session token to use with these credentials. Usually
     * present for temporary credentials.
     */
    readonly sessionToken?: string;
    }
```

When I instantiate the Credentials object:

```
    const credentials: aws_types.Credentials = {
       accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
       secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET,
    };
```

I get the following error:
`Type string | undefined is not assignable to type string`
because the API is expecting the `accessKeyId` and `secretAcessKeyId` to be of type string, but in my case they're undefined because they're populated by environment variables. I'm wondering how to pass in a value that's undefined but will be of type string? Any help is appreciated

Comment: The issue isn't that the environment variable isn't defined yet, it's that the type of `process.env.<ANYTHING>` is `string | undefined` since the value may be undefined in general.

Comment: To fix the type error, you can do `process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ?? ""`, which will give either the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` environment variable or an empty string if the variable is `undefined` (or `null`), and overall has a type of `string`.

Answer (score 1):

In `aws-sdk` v2 they had types

```
accessKeyId?: string,
secretAccessKey?: string
```

but now in new v3 `@aws-sdk/client-s3` they removed this optional `?` mark so now we have this stupid typescript error.
For workaround I used [Henry Woody's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74117554/typescript-error-in-aws-serets-manger-type-string-undefined-is-not-assignabl#comment130861775_74117554)